# Cannot complete 'Old school Ghouls'

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I have Raul as a companion and I'm trying to do his companion quest (Old School Ghouls). I have finished talking to the person at Novac and the person at Camp Forlorn Hope. All I have to do now is talk to Loyal at the Nellis Air Force base, but I have one issue; my reputation with the boomers is Wild Child, and they attack me on sight.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: That could just mean you've prevented yourself from finishing that quest. It's easy to permanently close routes in these kinds of games.

Comment: Is your goal to complete the Quest or get Raul as a companion or Both? Because there is a way in which you can get Raul as a companion without that questline

Comment: @NathanTaylor If he's doing the quest, he already has Raul as a companion.

Comment: @Studoku Ah that wasn't made clear by the question at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in Wild Child status with the Boomers, your Fame and Infamy with that faction are both high.  There's not any faction armor for the Boomers, so you can't fake them out long enough to finish this quest.  There's no alternative to meeting with the Boomers if you want to finish this quest, either.

If you are playing on a PC and have access to the console, you can use console commands to reset your Infamy with the Boomers.  First, **note that [using the console disables achievements until the game has been quit and reloaded.](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_achievements_and_trophies)**  Second, **make a backup copy of your save so that if something goes wrong you can recover.**

While in the game, press the <kbd>`</kbd> key and then enter the following command:

`setreputation 000ffae8 0 0`

If you're starting from Wild Child, this should take your Boomers reputation to Idolized.